# Checking adjacent tiles in 2-dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays

So i'm trying to make a game of Connect Four in Java, instead I'm connecting 6 instead of 4.

I have a 2-dimensional array and X amount of players. I have to check if 6 blocks in succession (horizontal, vertical and diagonal) are marked by the same player. If they are, the program should print who won.

Now, I don't have problems with the checking or determining who won, though for the life of me I can't figure out how to prevent the program from crashing whenever it tries to check for a block that's outside the array.

Now, I'm trying to avoid using try-catch or plopping 8 loops one after the other, and instead use one method for all of the directions with just variation in the parameters but I can't seem to make it work :\

Does anyone have a suggestion on how this might work?

I'm a beginner in programming and I've possibly missed something so that's why I'm asking for help :)

Cheers

Edit: here's the code. It's a bit long, that's why i want to shorten it and make it work somehow. the Terminal class is the same as the System.out.println one.

```
void checkIfPlayerWins(Field field, Integer rowNumber, Integer colNumber) {
    Integer counter = 1;

    for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
        if (field.isOccupied(rowNumber, colNumber + i)) {
            counter++;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
        if (field.isOccupied(rowNumber - i, colNumber + i)) {
            counter++;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
        if (field.isOccupied(rowNumber - i, colNumber)) {
            counter++;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
        if (field.isOccupied(rowNumber - i, colNumber - i)) {
            counter++;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
        if (field.isOccupied(rowNumber, colNumber - i)) {
            counter++;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
        if (field.isOccupied(rowNumber + i, colNumber - i)) {
            counter++;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
        if (field.isOccupied(rowNumber + i, colNumber)) {
            counter++;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
        if (field.isOccupied(rowNumber + i, colNumber + i)) {
            counter++;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    if (counter == 6) {
        Terminal.printLine("");
    }
}
```

here's the isOccupied method

```
boolean isOccupied(Integer x, Integer y) {
    return !this.field[x][y].equals("**");

}
```

Comment: Why are you having trouble with checking "for a block thats outside the array"?

Comment: Well, for example if the IF conditional is checking a block that is outside the bonds of the array, for example if i'm searching for array[20][20] that is 19x19 in size, an out of bonds exception is thrown

Comment: So just limit your checking by the size of the array. IE if you know the array is 20x20 then dont check for anything higher than 19 or lower than 0 in either dimension.

Comment: It would be more efficient, I believe to post the code rather than telling us about it.

Comment: posted the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply handle the case where you're attempting to check whether the `Field` is occupied at **invalid coordinates** in your `isOccupied` method:

```
boolean isOccupied(Integer x, Integer y) {
    if(x < 0 || y < 0 || x >= numberOfColumns || y >= numberOfRows) {
        // Attempting to check outside the grid: it's non-occupied.
        return false;
    }

    return !this.field[x][y].equals("**");
}
```